# Django servering static files not working with dev server

Tags: python, django

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I can't get this to work.  I'm using Django 1.3 and Python 2.7.

My project structure looks like this:

```
project
   static
   templates
   settings.py
   apps
      ...
```

In my settings.py file I have

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'))
STATIC_URL = '/static'
```

my urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')),
) 
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

In my templates, I'm using `{{ STATIC_URL }}` which creates the correct path to my files, like this: `/static/js/libs/modernizr-2.0.6.min.js`.

None of my static files load and I've double checked the directory structure is correct.  I feel like I'm taking crazy pills, so any advice is appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the complete path to the dir where you place your static files in STATICFILES_DIRS in settings.py, like this:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
                '/path/to/static',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Either add STATICFILES_DIRS as in previous answer or put the package directory that has 'static' dir in your INSTALLED_APPS because django will automatically serve any static dir in apps during development. If your `project` directory is not on python path and you're not planning to make it importable then you have to define STATICFILES_DIRS and put absolute path to the static directory.